# Overriding Sentinel Package

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I want to override the activation package of sentinel package using Laravel. Can anyone tell me the easiest and efficient way in Laravel to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override or replace route for activation in Sentinel with your own route.